# Should I add sound effects to my web site?

Tags: web-app, sound, sound-effects

I'm considering adding sound effects for interaction on my site. I'm fond of the quick, < 1/4s sound effects on iPhones when sending mail, messaging, etc. I'm thinking it gives a nice, positive feedback. The sound would play when a user clicks a voting button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we use a sound/jingle when users arrive on our site or open our app?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30359/should-we-use-a-sound-jingle-when-users-arrive-on-our-site-or-open-our-app)

Comment: @KitGrose It is not the same question. I already read that. That question asks if music should play upon visit, which I don't agree with.

Comment: Not the same question, but it has some helpful advice, check this question; [Is it recommended to play a sound for warning and error messages?][1]. Basically, play sounds to alert or attract user attention. [1]:https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52898/is-it-recommended-to-play-a-sound-for-warning-and-error-messages

Comment: @Chloe fair enough; I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: 99.9% of the time the answer is: no.

Comment: No. Awful. But if you must, **disable them by default and let the user explicitly choose to enable them**. Nothing worse then being somewhere where you're supposed to be quiet or where only certain sounds are acceptable (at work, in an audience, or even doing something else that requires sound with your computer connected to some speakers) and having surprise sounds on a web site. Bonus annoying points if you can't disable them without muting *all* sounds on your system.

Comment: Also have a look here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52898/is-it-recommended-to-play-a-sound-for-warning-and-error-messages/52900#52900

Comment: How is this question on-topic? This is ***very*** opinion based.

Comment: @CodeMaverick So is pretty much every other question on this site.

Comment: For the love of God, NO!

Comment: I hate, with a passion, the websites that play audio on load. There have been quite a few times when I have avoided restaurants whose websites played music whenever I opened their menus.

Comment: [This page](http://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/nooo.swf.mp3) pretty comprehensively answers your question.  :)

Comment: @chipperyman573 - Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Sorry, I disagree... As you can see from the answers, almost everyone thinks "No, except in very special circumstances". I haven't seen anyone say "Yeah it's a great idea". So at the very least there's a consensus on what constitutes good design. I don't see what else you'd expect on UX?

Comment: @OP What happens if your user has your site open in multiple tabs? Are they all beeping/clicking away?

Comment: @Basic - No, the consensus is on what constitutes **bad** design.

Comment: It's as opinion based as asking "if I press the button on this air horn every 10 minutes, will that annoy people?" :)

Comment: These comments and answers are mostly knee-jerk reactions to sound poorly implemented on sites. It can be done well, subtly, at only the right moments.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesCalo perhaps partly, but while there certainly is *poor* sound implementation there are also very objective reasons as to why sounds should be avoided in general on web pages. Yes, there are rare exceptions where it can be a nice thing (one example being when used very sparingly as a background alert)

Comment: Here is an example of a website that uses sounds for the buttons. http://www.whatsmyip.org/ip-geo-location/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Context is important here. Sound feedback can be very useful when people need or expect it. The ATM. That annoying credit card pad that only accepts a button push every 3rd time at the pharmacy check out line. A cash register.

And *maybe* it can be important for your web site, but realize that that is a very atypical behavior and not something your users are likely expecting. Beyond alert sounds, most computer operating systems, and therefore web browsers, and therefore web sites do not by default have any sort of user-input sound effects. There's likely two good reasons for this.

1. It'd be pretty annoying if every menu click or keyboard tab produced an audible 'click' on your computer. You'd tire of it very quickly. Unlike the previous examples which are UI's you use sporadically, for many people their computer is an 8+ hour of day device. Like our kids, sometimes the less noise they make, the more we tolerate them. :)
2. Any sounds above and beyond alert sounds would make alert sounds less effective. If everything is making a sound, then effectively nothing is making a sound.

And then there's the practical side of things. Lots of people are wearing headphones while on their computer. Listening to music. Or skyping. Or what have you. They are in control of the sound on their machine and may not be thrilled that your web site has decided to add to that.

And most work environments either frown upon or just omit speakers from the workplace machines altogether. So keep those things in mind.

But like most rules-of-thumb, if you have a really good reason to break the rule, absolutely give it a shot.

Comment: `Any sounds above and beyond alert sounds would make alert sounds less effective. If everything is making a sound, then effectively nothing is making a sound.` Well put. @Chloe I would advice only using sounds for notifications or other things that need immediate attention from the user.

Comment: I hate those buttons.

Comment: `It'd be pretty annoying if every menu click or keyboard tab produced an audible 'click' on your computer`  You mean like that stupid default IE navigation click?  Friggin' hate that sound!

Comment: @istrasci First thing _everyone_ disables on a new windows machine

Comment: @Basic What, Internet Explorer?

Comment: @JamieBull I mean the "Navigation" sound used by IE and Explorer but yes, IE itself is a close 2nd :)

Answer (score 16):

I would ordinarily not offer an opinion here (as I am just barely worthy to read this site), but I would remind everyone that while the vast majority of users are sighted, introducing sounds can interfere with visually impaired users. If you do add sound (which I think is an excellent idea), please make sure that you include a way for those with difficulties to turn them off.

Conversely, hearing impaired users probably won't have speakers.

Answer (score 9):

Sound effects are a type of attraction to the user, true. But take care of the following things while implementing sound:

1. The sound should be pleasant, which means it should not be annoying or irritating. Different people have different preferences. Be aware of that.
2. People working working at offices prefer silence. If a user opens your website and a sound starts playing while at work it could be an uncomfortable situation. If he doesn't know how to stop the sound, he will *close the website*.
3. Sound definitely will take extra time to load.
4. For the front page, I would recommend *not* playing sound. Alternatively you could provide a POP like something asking the user whether they want sound or not. Keep a record of that, and after a few days / weeks, just check how many there are who preferred sound. You will get your answer from that.

Comment: not just at the office. If a website starts blaring sounds at me I close it and don't come back. Being able to turn it off makes no difference.

Comment: "If a user opens your website and a sound starts playing while at work it could be an uncomfortable situation." -- ah, the strange world of people who (a) don't want any sound from their computer at work/library/whatever, and yet (b) do not completely mute their speakers under those circumstances. I'm not saying those people don't exist and don't need our sympathy, but I don't understand them ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, there are people who want some sounds and don't want others.  For example, an IM notification from a customer is welcome, but an advertising pitch from a website is not.

Comment: @Mark: I was referring to the section of this answer that starts "people working at offices prefer silence". So, while there are indeed people who want audible IM notifications but not ads, they are not the people under discussion in that section. People who want silence but don't mute their sound are Doing Silence Wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Sound is like the [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element) & [Marquee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) tags - it may seem like a great idea to the page designer, but most users will **hate** it (while a few might **like**).

I.e., you will create a lot of ill will with a lot of people at the price of a little good will with a few.

Do **not** do it.

Comment: They're far worse than blink / marquee. The scope of blink's annoyance was limited to the user viewing the page. Sounds affect everybody nearby and are highly intrusive. It's also worth noting, I think, that the same considerations for sounds on web pages should be given to sounds in desktop applications as well.

Answer (score 3):

Quite honestly, no.

If you want to try adding sounds then make them optional for the user to turn them on, not to turn them off. But I would be surprised if you have over 1% of users opting to turn them on and any that do will turn them off again rather quickly.

Whilst the lines are blurring, a website is not an OS, nor is it a device — as previous posters have pointed out this is atypical behaviour for a website to the point of confusing rather than helpful.

Others have made the point that this could be helpful feedback for visually impaired users, so if that is a large proportion of your users then maybe, but otherwise I would wholeheartedly avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Chloe, I think sound effects are completely underutilized in web UX and I encourage you to include them.... when attached to events that the sound would bring meaning to of course.

Meaning, if you are thinking of bringing the midi background music back from the 90's, please don't. But if you are notifying a user of an event that has enough weight to get their attention I think it's a great idea. Just don't make an arcade. Use sparingly :)

Post your site here when you do and let us know any feedback on the sounds you apply.

Comment: If you must, disable them by default and let the user explicitly choose to enable them. Nothing worse then being somewhere where you're supposed to be quiet (or where only certain sounds are tolerated) and having surprise sounds on a web site. Extra irritating if the only way to disable them is to mute *all* sounds.

Comment: It's underutilized for a reason.

Comment: No no no no no excessive sounds are one of the most terribly annoying things you could possibly put on a site.

Comment: @Venemo, You are right, the reason is nobody knows how to handle them and they were up until recently difficult to incorporate. Sound is an integral part of our mobile world, I think the desktop should catch up. I stand by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With multi-tab browsing becoming the norm, your uses may often times have the page open but not visible.

And few things are more annoying that trying to figure out what tab is playing sounds you don't want.

If you do add them, make them off by default. And only add them to actions where they enhance the user experience. For example, in Mail on the Mac, I will hit send and then immediately switch to a different program or move to the next message. The "jet send" sound effect lets me know that yes the message sent. It is audible confirmation that I no longer need to worry that the message sent. IF you add sound effect to your site they should serve a similar purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use sound.. its a way back story, when you used to have sound/Music on your sites..mostly with flash sites. Think..if you are opening a site in your office and all of a sudden a music plays and you do not know how to turn it off..and now everyone is looking at yourself... embarrassing..ehn?

having said that this is completely dependable on your business or what you want to portrait to your user. You can certainly give provision to turn it on if user want to.

Comment: Not sure you read the question. It's not music, and it's not when they open the page. It's sound effects, when they click on something.

Comment: yup! multiple clicks will create music for sure!!!

Answer (score 1):

Give him an option to play sound, but don't play by default. If he loves music in every clicks  he will definitely find it and enable it

Comment: It's not music, it is just sound effects.